# Function trouble with EOF

Tags: c++, function, c++11, char, eof

I have a function that is supposed to read a file char by char and output to console until it reaches EOF. The function works fine displaying all the characters I want, but then it just keeps going, and never stops at the end.

Below is the function

```
 void displayAllLines(ifstream &joke)
 {
    char ch;
    joke.clear();
    ch = joke.get();
    while (ch != EOF)
    {
        cout << ch;
        ch = joke.get();
    } 
 }
```

Contents of the file listed below

"(blank line)
Q: What did the tongue say to the teeth?"

As I stated, it displays the line just fine, but the loop keeps going after the question mark.

Any thoughts on why this might be? Also, is more information needed to properly answer my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical way of doing this is:

```
 void displayAllLines(ifstream &joke)
 {
    char ch;
    while (true)
    {
        ch = joke.get();
        if (joke) {
             cout << ch;
        } else {
             break;
        }
    } 
 }
```

The expression `joke` will evaluate to true until it hits EOF. I am not sure why you would want to call `joke.clear()` first.

Comment: It's just a habit I was taught when starting out with a file. Just making sure there are no flags on it at the beginning. Do you think it's pointless, or do you think it's possibly harmful to a program?

EDIT:: As for the code you posted, it certainly progresses the program further, but does not account for space characters, and displays everything with no spaces

Comment: Also, curious if you have any thoughts why my code *doesn't* work.

Comment: Ii do not think you should blindly call ``clear()``. If there are flags set, then it would be for a reason and simply clearing them will not help. Your code does not work because C++ streams do not read EOF as a character as C does. C++ streams read characters until they hit EOF. (They never actually return the EOF character--that is a C thing.)

Comment: Why is it that the posted code skips white space? I don't see why the space char wouldn't be recognized.

Comment: Sorry. I am used to reading strings not characters. ``joke >> str`` will skip whitespace (which is what I do most of the time). I updated the answer to use ``joke.get()`` as you do in your question.

Comment: Ah, when reading from a file I have always done it with chars. That does exactly what I need it to do! Now to figure out why my punchline file isn't reading! Thanks a heap Phil

Comment: The above loop can be simplified to this: `while (joke >> ch) { cout << ch; }`

Answer (score 1):

@Phil answered "how to do this in C++". My answer goes into "why is this happening" and "how to do this in C" (it still works in C++).

---

Since the ASCII table goes all the way from 1 up and we have byte value 0 (`'\0'`) reserved for string termination *(talking C and C++ languages)*, the EOF needs to be a special value outside of it.

That's why `getchar()` and also [`ifstream::get()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/) return an `int`, not a `char`. So all you need to do is change

```
char ch;
```

to

```
int ch;
```

and cast it to char for printing:

```
cout << (char) ch;
```

Technically, EOF is usually `-1`. Your `char` may have range `0 - 255`, which means it will never be equal to `-1`. A decent compiler with `-Wall` enabled should give you at least a warning though.

Comment: More generally, instead of `int` use `std::istream::traits_type::int_type`. That works for all character encodings, not just ASCII.